# How to use multiple strings to match string prefix in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to match below strings for the prefix.

customer

client

agent

If my string contains any of the above, i want to ignore.

```
let str = "customer_service"

if(!str.startsWith("customer") && !str.startsWith("client") && !str.startsWith("agent"))
    return true;
```

Any easy and effective solution available? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `let str = 'customer_service'`? WIth your code, `str` is simply assigned the value of a **variable** called `customer_service`

Comment: you want to discard customer, client and agent right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the string against a regular expression. If not match then proceed and ignore otherwise.

```
const regex = /^(customer|client|agent).*/;
const str = "customer_service";

if (!regex.test(str)) {
  // Ignored.
  // Do whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: Amazing!  Worked like a charm! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Actually best idea :)

Comment: Thank you @GrégoryNEUT

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to look for words or patterns:

```js
const strings = [
  "customer_service",
  "wookies",
  "bananas",
  "hats",
  "guys named steve",
  "agent_request",
  "client_lunch_order",
];

// test pattern for the given words
const regex = m = /(customer|agent|client)/;

// test the given string against the pattern
const filterFn = str => !m.test(str)

// run the list through the filter
const filteredList = strings.filter(filterFn);

// display the filtered list
console.log(filteredList);
```